# Read access violation error on trying to open a file

Tags: c, file, fopen

I am trying to check if a file exists by opening it with fopen() and then checking if the function returns `NULL`. But when I run the code, it says a read access violation error accured, but I don't get why, since I checked and the file I am trying to read is txt and has text already written in it. Can someone explain why and how I can fix it?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int quit = FALSE;
    if (fopen(*(argv+2), 'r') == NULL)
    {
        printf("Invalid input! File does not exit.");
        quit = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: fopen requires the second argument to be a string, not a char. Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: You're not saving the value returned by `fopen` (perhaps merely removed for the sake of minimizing the code); how do you intend to use it?  In general (doesn't apply in this case, since the invalid type of the mode is making the call invalid), you want to check the value in `errno` after `fopen` fails by doing something like `path=argv[2]; fp = fopen(path, "r"); if( fp == NULL) { perror( path ); ... } `

Comment: `*(argv+2)` why not `argv[2]`

Comment: Argument `'r'` is string `"r"`. Pay attention to all warnings. It would be very simple to add `printf( "file: %s\n", *(argv+2) );` before `fopen` and see the real name of file you are trying to open.

Comment: @Lundin experience talks.

Comment: We can close this as simple typo (it's not a bad question, this shouldn't even compile, yet it did). But for reference, any compiler that made a binary out of this non-conforming C code is bad or mis-configured. `gcc -pedantic-errors` should be a mandatory compiler option for everyone.

Comment: @Lundin thank you it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, from the [`fopen` manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html), we can see that the function signature is:

```
FILE *fopen(const char *pathname, const char *mode);
```

What this means is that it will return a pointer of type `FILE`, and expects two arguments, both pointers to `char`. The second argument you pass to `fopen` in your code is a `char`, not a `char*`, so we need to fix that. Also, store the returned `fopen` pointer, as you should use it to close the file after you're done with it.

So, your code would be something like:

```
FILE *fp;

if ((fp = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("File does not exist!\n");
    exit(0);
} else {
    /* file exists... do stuff */
    fclose(fp);
}
```